# Problem to solve sympy symbolic equation with tanh

Tags: python, sympy, hyperbolic-function

I write the following equation `my_Eq`. `a` and `b` are reals.

```
a,b=sp.symbols('a,b',real=True)
my_Eq=sp.Eq(sp.tanh(a),b)
```

When I tried to solve it : `sp.solve(my_Eq,a)`, two solutions are found : `[log(-sqrt(-(b + 1)/(b - 1))), log(sqrt(-(b + 1)/(b - 1)))]`

In the first solution, `a` is the log of something negative. Why did I obtained this solution because `a` and `b` are declared `reals` ?

After, `log`, `sqrt` are used. How is to possible to have something very simple : `a=atanh(b)`

Answer (score 1):

You might have an imaginary solution (i.e., not something negative):

```py
>>> b=S(-2)
>>> -sqrt(-(b + 1)/(b - 1))
-sqrt(3)*I/3
>>> _.is_real
False
>>> b.is_real
True
```

If you just want the inverse (which is not always a valid solution) you could explicitly do so, maybe like:

```py
eq = my_Eq
try:
     af = eq.lhs.inverse()
     print(Eq(eq.lhs.args[0], af(eq.rhs)))
except:
    raise ValueError('no inverse for lhs')
```